# One-To-Many, One-To-One in Google Closure (ala ExtJS Models, Backbone relational etc..)

Tags: extjs, closures

Does Google Closure API have something similar to rich ExtJs Models and BackboneJS (combined with Backbone Relational) for one-to-many, one-to-one.

By that I mean if I have

```
{ name: "Fred", age: 20, addresses: [{street: "Flintstone way","country":"Bedrock"}] }
```

When this is deserialized the root aggregate is object instance with the prototype Person and addresses is a collection of with prototype of Address.

I scanned the API docs but cant see anything clear and blogs etc about Closure are particularly quite

Comment: Does the title match the question?

Comment: Thanks. That was another question Im still drafting.

Answer (score 0):

```
flinstonesHouseholds = [
{
  "street":"1 Flinstone way",
  "country":"Bedrock",
  "people":[{name:"Fred",...},[{name:"Wilma",...}]
},
{
  "street":"2 Flinstone way",
  "country":"Bedrock",
  "people":[{name:"Barney",...},[{name:"Betty",...}]
}
]
```

Would restructuring the way you're packaging the data per the above solve your problem? Or are we assuming multiple addresses per flinstones character in which case your problem is many to many. Barring additional complexity, there shouldn't be any one to one or one to many relationships that can't be baked right into your JSON/array payloads. Let me know if you'd need help navigating this structure to return the results you want and I'll elaborate.